# Movie about a guy who contacts an alien through farts

Tags: story-identification, aliens

It was a movie that I saw in cinema when I was a very little child, in 1984 or 1985. The movie was either italian or french. It was a very rough and unelegant comedy.

What I remember is the main character was a lonely old dude who lived in a house by the countryside. One night he farted like a lot, and a humanoid alien heard him and came to visit him. They became friends and farted together.

The movie was probably an absolute piece of crap, but I really want to find it for curiosity.

Comment: Well that sounds...special

Comment: I'm reminded of the Red Nose Day Doctor Who parody "The Curse of Fatal Death" in which the Doctor (Rowan "Mr. Bean" Atkinson) communicates with the Master by farting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who:_The_Curse_of_Fatal_Death

Answer (score 6):

### *La Soupe aux Choux* (AKA *Cabbage Soup*)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Soupe_aux_choux):

> Claude Ratinier (Louis de Funès), known as Le Glaude, is an old man who lives on a small farm across the road from his long-time friend Francis Chérasse (Jean Carmet), known as Le Bombé. The two are described as the last surviving members of their breed, still living in a rural fashion while the rest of the world has modernized. They spend their days getting drunk and eating cabbage soup, while they spend their nights getting drunk and farting.
>
> One night, their farting summons an alien (Jacques Villeret) from the planet Oxo while Le Bombé is asleep. Glaude is awake to welcome the alien (who can only communicate in a squealing-siren sound at first).